# Multi-national teams at club level

Tags: international-sports

I am trying to find out if there are any notable teams, in any sport, that are recognized at some level as part of two or more national bodies.
For example, imagine if the neighbouring Słubice (Poland) and Frankfurt an der Oder (Germany) had a joint  team, recognised in some form by both the Polish and German federations for said sport.

I would like to find teams that participate in at least one official national and/or international competition for clubs.
I am **not** interested in: invitational teams and other similar groups that are assembled for exhibition mathces only, such as the Barbarians in rugby; multi-national sides competing officially only against national sides or similar multi-national sides, such as West Indies in cricket.

If any such teams exists, please provide some details about which organisations they belong to, which competitions they take part in, and more generally which rules regulate or limit their multi-national nature.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of anomalies around the Home Countries. Perhaps the closest to what you're thinking about involves [Wrexham F.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrexham_F.C.), [Colwyn Bay F.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colwyn_Bay_F.C.) and [Merthyr Town F.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merthyr_Town_F.C.), all of whom compete in the English football league and cup competitions, but are governed by the Football Association of Wales for administrative purposes. The more famous Welsh clubs in the top four tiers of the English league system are governed by the F.A., and are thus exclusively English clubs, despite actually playing in Wales.